# jquery TimeCircles has stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, timer

Need your help with my TimeCircles count down timer implementation.

The overall concept is like that:

I have a div on my page reserved for countdown timer

```
<div id="countdown" style="width:150px;float:right">
```

Then I retrieve timer value within JSON from PHP-script using GET method

```
$.getJSON("/app/test/catcher.php",{choice:answer},function(data){//blah-blah
```

Based on that value (data.timeout) I modify countdown div and create timer bound to that div using data-timer attribute (whith prior destroying of last instance of the timer)

```
if(data.timeout>0){
var timer=$('#countdown').TimeCircles({
"bg_width": 0.1,
"fg_width": 0.1,
"circle_bg_color": "#6f6f6f",
"count_past_zero": false,
"time":{
"Days":{"show":false},
                    "Hours":{"show":false},
                    "Minutes":{"show":false},
                    "Seconds":{"text":"","color":"#E73263"}
                }
            });
            timer.destroy();
            $('#countdown').attr('data-timer',data.timeout);
            timer.rebuild();
```

So, the problem is that every time I set data-timer value it is changing accordingly in my html code but timer is stubbornly stuck to the very first value of data-timer. I've spent a lot of time trying to fix that issue and all in vain, so I'd appreciate any your suggestions on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the creator of jQuery TimeCircles.

First, make sure you're using the latest version.

Then: You shouldn't need to have to destroy it every time. Instead, TimeCircles currently reads the `data-timer` using the jQuery `.data('timer')`

This attribute doesn't change when the attribute changes, but does change when set using `.data('timer', 10)`.

You should be able to reduce your code to:

```
$("#countdown").data('timer', parseInt(data.timeout)).TimeCircles().restart();
```

I hope this helps!